# View state size limit & de-reference null for transient

Tags: attachment, dml, visualforce, pagereference, viewstate

I have below code to allow multiple file attachments to be inserted against a parent record id. But this results in either View state size limit exceeded (not all the time) or dereferencing null object at below line(when using transient to by pass view state).
Can someone please help me here?

Code snippet:

```
public Pagereference SaveAttachments()  
    {  
        String callId='a04L0000003SQZV';//remove later
        //String callId = System.currentPagereference().getParameters().get('id');  
        if(callId == null || callId == '')  
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'No record is associated. Please pass record Id in parameter.'));  
        if(Counting== null )  
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Please select how many files you want to upload.'));  

        transient List<Attachment> listToInsert = new List<Attachment>() ;  

        //Attachment a = new Attachment(parentId = callId, name=myfile.name, body = myfile.body);  
        for(Attachment a: allFileList)  // Null Pointer error
        {  
            if(a.name != '' && a.name != '' && a.body != null)  
                listToInsert.add(new Attachment(parentId = callId, name = a.name, body = a.body)) ;  
        }  

        //Inserting attachments  
        if(listToInsert.size() > 0)  
        {  

            insert listToInsert ;  

            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, listToInsert.size() + ' file(s) are uploaded successfully'));  
            Counting= 0 ;  
        }  
        else  
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Please select at-least one file'));  
        //allFileList=null;

        return null;  
    }  

    public PageReference ChangeCount()  
    {  
        allFileList.clear() ;  //  Error with de-reference null object
        Counting=Counting+1;  //
        //Adding multiple attachments instance  
        for(Integer i = 1 ; i <= Counting; i++)  //Integer.valueOf(FileCount) 
            allFileList.add(new Attachment()) ;  
        return null ;  
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `allFileList.clear() ;` try

```
allFileList = new List<Attachment>();
```

when using `transient` that variable will become `null` as  soon as the method terminates. So you can not call any method on `null` object.

Comment: Now I am getting below error at mentioned line.    Error: NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Comment: @SFDC_GEEK when using transient keywork you can not maintain state of that variable. So if you call another action the transient variable will become null.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to get it resolved?